# How Dependency injection with @Inject annotation works in micronaut Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, jvm, micronaut

how to inject dependencies in class with @Inject annotation for micronaut framework

```
@Controller("/")
class HelloController(val greetService:GreetService){

 @Get("/hello")
 fun getMessage(){
    greetService.greet 
  }

}

class GreetService(val userRepo:UserRepo){

  fun doSomething(val data:String){
      userRepo.saveData(data)
  } 
}
class UserRepo(val db:DbHandler){
     fun saveData(val data){
       db.save(data)
     }
}
```

how to use @Inject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @Singleton
 class GreetService(val userRepo:UserRepo){

 fun doSomething(val data:String){
  userRepo.saveData(data)
     } 
   }
```

the bean you want to inject has to be declared as bean as per Micronaut using provided annotations such as @Singleton , @Context ,@ThreadLocal etc

Answer (score 3):

It's not any different you can write something like this :

```
@Inject
var greetingService:GreetingService;
```

Or you could do it on the constructor

```
class HelloController(@Inject val greetService:GreetService)
```

I prefer the second option because it uses val over var.

Comment: I think `class HelloController(val greetService:GreetService)` will work just as `class HelloController(@Inject val greetService:GreetService)`.

Comment: It isn't because of @Controller.  It would work in any bean in the context (including but not limited to controllers).